# How to write an new line and string after the first occurrence of a string in in an file Python

Tags: python

I would like to write an new line and string after the first the first occurrence of a string in Python
For example my text file is like:

```
123456
example string<random>
asdfg
zxc
example string<random>
```

I would like it to change to

```
123456
example string<random>
Python inputted string
asdfg
zxc
example string<random> <- Stays the same
```

Comment: I think maybe it could be useful if you could mention the bigger picture of what you're trying to achieve here. The task seems oddly specific that maybe there's a better way of doing it

Comment: `mutable_seq = list(string); mutable_seq.insert(mutable_seq.index(pattern) + 1, 'inserted string'); new_string = ''.join(mutable_seq)`

Comment: Its to inject code after the first function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read lines from file

```
lines = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    lines.append(line)

with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
  flag = True
  for line in lines:
    f.write(line)
    if line.startswith("example string") and flag:
      f.write("what ever\n")
      flag = False
```

input file

```
123456
example string<random>
asdfg
zxc
example string<random>
```

output file

```
123456
example string<random>
what ever
asdfg
zxc
example string<random>
```

Comment: I did that but the result is an blank text file

Comment: @projectuser, provided more specific code...

Comment: That does not allow for <random>

Comment: You can fix it by changing line 10 to `if line.find("example string") and flag:`

Comment: @projectuser then replace `if line.strip() == "example string<random>"`  with `if line.startswith("example string")`